ODE has many tangent solutions
This is perhaps one of the most over-asked questions on this site: say here, or here. However, the answers are not satisfactory, especially of the second assertion. The first assertion is straightforward. For the second one I have some intuition, but it doesn't seem to be easily fixed as a formal proof. I have writen below what I have tried.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$ and $r\in \mathbb{R}$ a fixed point. Consider the following ODE: $$x'=f(x/t)$$ Prove that:
First Assertion If $f'(r)<1$, no solution is tangent to $g(t)=rt$ at $0$.
Second Assertion If $f'(r)>1$, there are infinitely many solutions tangent to $g(t)=rt$ at $0$.

General Observations:
At first, we notice that $g(t)$ is indeed a solution. This is straightforward:
$$g'(t)=r=f\left(r\right)=f\left(\frac{rt}{t}\right)$$
Here is another observation. $F(x,t)=f(x/t)$ is locally Lipschitz for $t\not=0$. Indeed, we have that for all $(x,t),(y,t)\in B(x_o,\varepsilon)\times B(t_o,\varepsilon)$.
$$|F(x,t)-F(y,t)|=\left|f'(\xi)\left(\frac{x}{t}-\frac{y}{t}\right)\right|=\frac{|x-y|}{|t|^2}|f'(\xi)|\leq  \frac{M}{(|t_o|-\varepsilon)^2}|x-y|$$
Where $M$ is finite as taken to be the supremum over a compact set, namely:
$$M=\sup_{k\in \{x/t| (x,t)\in B(x_o\varepsilon)\times B(t_o,\varepsilon)\}}|f'(k)|$$
Because $F(x,t)$ is taken to be locally Lipschitz, solutions must be locally unique by Piccard's Theorem. If $h(t)$ is a solution in different then $g(t)=rt$, then if they met at a point, they would be locally the same in a neighborhood of that point.
Suppose by way of contradiction that they meet at a point and thus, we may consider $I=\{t| g(t)=h(t)\}\cap[a,b] $ a nonempty set for large $b$ and small $a$ with $b>a>0$. It is the preimage of zero by continuous functions intersected with a closed set so it is closed. Thus, it must contain its infimum and supremum. If the infimum is not equal to $a$ we find a contradiction, because $g$ and $h$ coincide in the infimum being continuous functions, so the infimum wouldn't be a lower bound by Piccard's condition. Thus, $g$ and $h$ coincide everwhere and the same argument holds for $b$. Hence, $h$ and $g$ coincide in $\mathbb{R}^+$.
This means that if $f$ and $g$ are different in $\mathbb{R}^+$, they must never meet and we may restrict ourselves to the two cases: $h(t)<rt$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}^+$ or $h(t)>rt$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}^+$. Suppose without loss of generality that $r\in \mathbb{R}^+$
Proof of the first assertion:
Case I: $h(t)<rt$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}^+$.
Suppose by way of contradiction that the solutions are tangent. In case I, it is true that: $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{h(t)-rt}{t}=0$ which in turn implies that:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{h(t)-rt}{t}=\frac{(f(h(t)/t)-r)t-(h(t)-rt)}{t^2}=\frac{f'(\xi(t))(h(t)/t-r)t-(h(t)-rt)}{t^2}=$$
$$\frac{\left(f'(\xi(t))-1\right)\left(\frac{h(t)}{t}-r\right)}{t}$$
Where $\frac{h(t)}{t} \leq\xi(t)\leq r $. This in turn means that for small $t$ by continuity of $f'$ and the fact that $f'(\xi(t))<1$, $h(t)<rt$:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{h(t)-rt}{t}>0 \quad \text{for $t\in (0,\varepsilon)$}$$
By the mean value theorem we have that:
$$0<\left.\frac{d}{dt}\frac{h(t)-rt}{t}\right|_{\xi\in (0,\varepsilon/2)}\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\frac{h(\varepsilon/2)-r\varepsilon/2}{\varepsilon/2}-0<0$$
$0<0$ is a clear contradiction which finishes this case.
Case II: $h(t)>rt$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}^+$.
Suppose by way of contradiction again that solutions are tangent. It still holds that:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{h(t)-rt}{t}=\frac{\left(f'(\xi(t))-1\right)\left(\frac{h(t)}{t}-r\right)}{t}$$
Where $r\leq\xi(t)\leq \frac{h(t)}{t} $. This in turn means that for small $t$ by continuity of $f'$ and the fact that $f'(\xi(t))<1$, $h(t)>rt$:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{h(t)-rt}{t}<0 \quad \text{for $t\in (0,\varepsilon)$}$$
By the mean value theorem we have that:
$$0>\left.\frac{d}{dt}\frac{h(t)-rt}{t}\right|_{\xi\in (0,\varepsilon/2)}\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\frac{h(\varepsilon/2)-r\varepsilon/2}{\varepsilon/2}-0>0$$
$0>0$ is a clear contradiction which finishes this case.
"Heuristic" proof of the second assertion:
Consider any point $(t_o,x_o)\in \mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $x_o>t_o$. Clearly, by the Locally Lipschitz condition, there exists a solution passing through this point. Take the maximal solution $\gamma_{t_o,x_o}$ passing through this point.  Under the assumption the following limit exists and the solution is well defined in $\mathbb{R}^+$, using L'Hopital, we have:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\gamma_{x_o,t_o}(t)}{t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}\gamma_{x_o,t_o}'(t)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}f\left(\frac{\gamma_{x_o,t_o}(t)}{t}\right)$$
If $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\gamma_{x_o,t_o}(t)}{t}$ converges, it must converge to a fixed point of $f$ by the above equation once we use continuity of $f$. We also know that by the global dependence theorem it is true that for initial conditions close to $g(t)=rt$ we expect that $\gamma_{x_o,t_o}(t)$ will stay close to $g(t)$. But this means we also expect that the limit will change little and will remain existing and being close to $r$. However, we proved that in this case, the limit must be a fixed point, but because $f'(r)>1$, then close to $r$ there is only one fixed point: we are strictly above the line $y=x$ for slightly larger than $r$ values and strictly below for slightly smaller values of $r$. Hence, for every solution close enough to $g(t)$ we have a valid solution and there are infinitely many such solutions satisfying:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\gamma'_{x_o,t_o}(t)}{t}=r$$
Of course this argument is far from being formal.
